# Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location

Tags: c++, fstream

I was trying to output a specific line in the file using the find() and substr(), just to see if it works. As you can see i'm quite a beginner so i would appreciate any comments or tips on my code.

```
inFile.open("config.txt");
string content;
while (getline(inFile, content)){

    if (content[0] && content[1] == '/') continue;

    size_t found = content.find("citylocation.txt");
    string city = content.substr(found);

    cout << city << '\n';

}
```

Comment: `find` will fail every time except the one line that matches. You need to check `found` before trying to use it.

Comment: `content[0] && content[1] == '/'` this does not check if the line starts with `//`. It checks `(content[0]) && (content[1] == '/')`.

Comment: `content[0]` doesn't check if the line is empty, either. Undefined behavior, with a chance of a crash.

Comment: Furthermore, I'm quite confident that even if the line has at least two characters, `content[0] && content[1] == '/'` doesn't do what you think it does. It does not, I repeat, ***does not*** check if the first two characters in the line are slashes, as your likely intent is. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Gosh, three comments saying that `content[0] && content[1] == '/'` doesn't do what you want, but none of the three says how to write that test. Welcome to StackExchange! If you know that there are at least two characters in `content`, then you should check `content[0] == '/' && content[1] == '/'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple notes on the following excerpt:

```
content[0] && content[1] == '/'
```

When you write `content[0]` and `content[1]`, you're *assuming* that the characters at positions 0 and 1 exist, which is not necessarily the case. You should wrap this code in a condition like `if (content.size() >= 2){ ... }` To protect yourself from accessing string contents that don't exist.

Secondly, as currently written, this code will convert `content[0]` to `bool`, because of how the logical AND operator `&&` works. You should write `content[0] == '/' && content[1] == '/'` if you want to check that the first and second characters are both `'/'`

Furthermore, in the following snippet:

```
size_t found = content.find("citylocation.txt");
string city = content.substr(found);
```

What should happen if `"citylocation.txt"` can't be found in the string? `std::string::find` handles this by returning the special value `std::string::npos`. You should test against this to check if the substring could be found, again to prevent yourself from reading an invalid memory location:

```
size_t found = content.find("citylocation.txt");
if (found != std::string::npos){
    std::string city = content.substr(found);
    // do work with 'city' ...
}
```